# Why is this object coming out with the key twice in React and Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, object, post

This is following up with another question that I asked here: [Problems with POST in React and Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68914102/problems-with-post-in-react-and-node-js)

The object that I'm doing the console.log on in React is the data that I will be sending Node. Sending that data to Node is the next thing to do, I can do that but the data is not coming out the way that I want here. The data is in my "inputData" object and is taking the information out of the "username" and "password" input fields and organizing it so that it becomes the response from the fetch request which is in turn going to be sent to Node.

The problem is that I'm getting
{ username: { username: 'aa' }, password: { password: 'zz' } }
instead of
{username: 'aa', password: 'zz'}.
That "inputData" object says { username: {username}, password: {password}, }, so it seems like if I enter 'aa' and 'zz' for my username and password, those would be from my variables that I declared with useState, so I would get {username: 'aa', password: 'zz'}, but obviously that's not happening. Why am I getting the key back twice?

I can get it to work by making the "inputData" object { username, password, }, but I don't understand the logic behind why that way already generates key/value pairs.

server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const application = express();
const cors = require('cors');
application.use(cors());
application.use(express.json());
application.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

// routes are here
application.get('/', (request, response) => {
    response.send('Homepage');
});
application.get('/testAPI', (request, response) => {
    response.json('Test API working');
});
application.get('/register', (request, response) => {
    response.send('Register route');
});
application.post('/register', (request, response) => {
    response.json('Send response here');
    console.log(request.body);
});

// listen to server
application.listen(8080, () => {
    console.log('Listening here...');
});
```

App.js

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function App() {
  // basic state for things
  const [username, setUsername] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  const [data, setData] = useState('Data goes here');
  const [API, setAPI] = useState('Data from API goes here');

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('http://localhost:8080/testAPI')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => setAPI(data));
  }, []);

  const readUsername = (e) => {
    setUsername(e.target.value);
  };

  const readPassword = (e) => {
    setPassword(e.target.value);
  };

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const inputData = {
      username: {username},
      password: {password},
    };
    const requestCall = {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(inputData),
    };
    const result = await fetch('http://localhost:8080/register', requestCall);
    console.log(await result.json());
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <>
      <h1>Hello World!</h1>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} method="POST">
        <label htmlFor="username" name="username" >Username: </label>
        <input htmlFor="username" name="username" onChange={readUsername} />
        <br/>
        <label htmlFor="password" name="password" >Password: </label>
        <input htmlFor="password" name="password" type="password" onChange={readPassword} />
        <br/>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
      <h1>{API}</h1>
      </>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

This happens due to `username: {username}, password: {password}`. As Izac Cavalheiro said. It's the javascript shorthand, so yes, that happens...

Would be same as writing `{username: {username: username}}`

Also, you said you don't understand the logic behind that effect of not defining key/values when same named, this is called ***destructuring***, another shorthand.

You may do things like:

```
let username = "Some Name";
let password = "Password";

let User = {username, password};
// same as User = {username: username, password: password}

let {username, password} = User;
// will define two variables with same key and values as User's, since the User object contains them...
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change inputData object to be like that:

```
const inputData = {
  username: username,
  password: password,
};
```

Or using shorthand:

```
const inputData = {
  username,
  password,
};
```